# Failure to connect VisualVM to remote docker

Tags: java, docker, profiling, visualvm

I have a java docker that is running on remote host, I want want to monitor the memory from my host.
on the docker i have configured

```
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9090 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=0.0.0.0 \
 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0"
```

and exposed port 9090

from my host I have run
ssh -fN -D 7777  to create a tunnel

I have tested the connection with jconsole using

```
jconsole -J-DsocksProxyHost=localhost -J-DsocksProxyPort=7777 service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9090/jmxrmi -J-DsocksNonProxyHosts=
```

and all works fine - I see all the data.
Now I wont to monitor using VisualVM

I have added the SOCKS proxy --> localhost on port 7777
I have added remote connection and jmx endpoint

however I am getting disabled connection with no data. What I am missing?